# Knockout Regex validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am using Knockout.validation to validate my input fields in my page. At first, everything is going well until I tried to use regex. I really don't know what it is that I'm doing wrong, hope you can help me out.

Below is my script:

```
var self = this;
self.MobileNumber = ko.observable().extend({ pattern: { params: "^(?:04\d{2}|\({1}04\d{2}\){1})\s{0,1}(\d{3}(\s{0,1})\d{3})$", message: "Invalid mobile number."} });
```

And below is my HTML page:

```
<div>
    <input data-bind="value: MobileNumber, valueUpdate: 'blur'" />
</div>
<div>
    <p data-bind="validationMessage: MobileNumber">
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but what is your question? What is not working? Are you sure your regex is correct? Have you test it (with something like http://jsregex.com/)?

Answer (score 15):

The regex needs to be declared as a regex rather than a string, so instead of your line above I'd use

```
self.MobileNumber = ko.observable().extend({ 
    pattern: { 
        params: /^(?:04\d{2}|\({1}04\d{2}\){1})\s{0,1}(\d{3}(\s{0,1})\d{3})$/, 
        message: "Invalid mobile number."
    } 
});
```

In my own code I habitually set up an object of regex patterns to make it easy to reuse across my app...

```
var patterns = {
    email: /^([\d\w-\.]+@([\d\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,4})?$/,
    phone: /^\d[\d -]*\d$/,
    postcode: /^([a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9]?[a-zA-Z\s]?\s*[0-9][a-zA-Z]{2,2})|(GIR 0AA)$/
};
```

Then my ko looks like...

```
self.postcode = ko.observable().extend({
     required: true,
     pattern: {
         message: 'Must be a valid UK postcode',
         params: patterns.postcode
     }
});
```

Comment: this is no longer true, can be a string or a Regex now

Answer (score 2):

Please note if you're providing an object for `pattern` that you MUST include a `message`.

The regex can either be a string or a Regex literal.

**However:** If you're entering a pure string don't forget to escape any backslashes `'^\\d{5}(?:[-\\s]\\d{4})?$'` instead of `'^\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$'`

```
self.postcode = ko.observable().extend({
     required: true,
     pattern: {
         message: 'Must be a valid UK postcode',
         params: patterns.postcode
     }
});
```

The follow **doesn't** work, and leads to bizarre behavior (I think it is actually trying to match against the `toString()` value of the pattern parameter which gives very strange results).

```
self.postcode = ko.observable().extend({
     required: true,
     pattern: {
         params: patterns.postcode
     }
});
```

Alternatively you can just provide the pattern directly

```
self.postcode = ko.observable().extend({
     required: true,
     pattern:  patterns.postcode
});
```